# celluloid actor - how to terminate all actors with Celluloid.shutdown_timeout while using futures

Tags: ruby, jruby, celluloid

```
require 'celluloid/current'

Celluloid.shutdown_timeout = 1

class Mapper
  include Celluloid

  attr_accessor :value

  def run(num)
      @value = num.times.map { |idx| idx  } 
  end

end

 y = Mapper.spawn
 y.future.run(1000000)
```

---

Till now it seems to work and actors are shutdown after 1 second.

```
  y.value
```

But the moment I try to access value like above, it goes on till value returned from the method call is available.

My idea was to use Celluloid.shutdown_timeout just like standard  *Timeout.timeout(1) {}*

and terminate the block if it exceeds 1 sec time limit [*Timeout.timeout(1)* is notorious for misbehaving so not using it]

What's the right way to achieve this using celluloid actors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No. That is not how `shutdown_timeout` works.

`Celluloid.shutdown_timeout` is used `at_exit` to shutdown actors when the underlying process is being terminated. It is used when the process receives a kill signal.

You do need to put `Timeout.timeout {}` blocks in, but you are right, those do misbehave.